# Java - regex parse string

Tags: java, regex

Trying to parse out names with given samples

```
++++++++++++++++++SELIZABETH+COLLAZO+++++++++++++++++++
+++++++++++++++++++PALOMA+CORREA+++++++++++++++++++++++
+++++++++++++++++++NOAH+BLAKEMORE++++++++++++++++++++++
```

I've tried

```
//++(.*?)+(.*?)//++
```

but that's way off.

Would like to parse out the first and last name to two strings.

Comment: how about a split on `+` ?

Comment: Why are you matching `//` in your regex?

Comment: Why don't you just do `\w+`?

Comment: Did you mean to escape the `+` with `\\ ` instead of using `//`, and also to escape the one in the middle?

Comment: To match a literal `+`, you should escape it with ``\\`` in the Java string literal

Comment: `+` has special meaning in a regex, you have to escape them: `\\++(.*?)\\+(.*?)\\++`

Comment: You can use `^\++((?:[^+\s]*\+)+[^+\s]+)+` assuming an unknown number of names are possible and then split the resulting group on `+`

Answer (score 5):

You can use this regex `(\w+)\+(\w+)` or `\+{2,}(.*?)\+(.*?)\+{2,}` with Pattern like this :

```
String str = "++++++++++++++++++SELIZABETH+COLLAZO+++++++++++++++++++\n"
        + "+++++++++++++++++++PALOMA+CORREA+++++++++++++++++++++++\n"
        + "+++++++++++++++++++NOAH+BLAKEMORE++++++++++++++++++++++";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\w+)\\+(\\w+)");// or instead "\\+{2,}(.*?)\\+"(.*?)\\+{2,}
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);

while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1) + " " + matcher.group(2));
}
```

Outputs

```
SELIZABETH COLLAZO
PALOMA CORREA
NOAH BLAKEMORE
```

Comment: Hi down-voter, please put a comment when you down-vote a post, it is not legal to down-vote just like this, you have to respect the efforts of others, because we respect your efforts also. Thank you.